# Passing Environment Variables in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have looked through [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) which explains to do the following:

Note: since Gatsby uses the Webpack DefinePlugin to make the environment variables available at runtime, they cannot be destructured from `process.env`. Instead, they have to be fully referenced.

`GATSBY_API_URL` will be available to your site (client and server side) as `process.env.GATSBY_API_URL`.

I currently have this

```
useEffect(() => {
    var getRouteConfig = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/routes/${props.data.contentfulRoutes.slug}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_BEARER}`,
      },
    };

    axios(getRouteConfig)
      .then((res) => {
```

With `GATSBY_STRAVA_BEARER=2xxx` in my `.env` file. Along with other variables. Which I can access fine in `gatsby-config.js` I just can't seem to get them to render in my components.

If I was to log `process.env.GATSBY_STRAVA_BEARER` I get undefined

I only have `require('dotenv').config();` at the top of my `gatsby-config.js` file though.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-env-variables/

I'm use this in ourself project, it make access environment variables available at runtime. After install, declare this plugin in gatsby-config.

```
// gatsby-config.js
 module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-env-variables`,
      options: {
        allowList: ["APP_URL", "API_URL"]
      },
     },
   ],
 }
 
 // something component
 const Component = () => <div>{process.env.APP_URL}</div>
```